# Unity2D игрок не прыгает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу 2D шутер и начал делать передвижение. Я решил переделать код из этого [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puPjNRJMmOc) в 2D пространство и вышло это:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
private float speed;
public float WalkSpeed = 5f;
public float RunSpeed = 7f;
public float JumpForce = 6f;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector3 _normal;
private bool isFacingRight = true;
private Animator anim;
private bool is_ground;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) speed = RunSpeed; else speed = WalkSpeed;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, JumpForce); }

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Move(new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, move));
    anim.SetBool("Walk", move != 0);
    anim.SetBool("Run", speed == RunSpeed && move != 0);
    if (move > 0 && !isFacingRight)
        Flip();
    else if (move < 0 && isFacingRight)
        Flip();
}

public void Move(Vector3 direction)
{
    _ = Project(direction.normalized);
    Vector2 directionAlongSurface = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right;
    Vector2 offset = speed * Time.deltaTime * directionAlongSurface;

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + offset);
}

public Vector3 Project(Vector3 forward)
{
    return forward - Vector3.Dot(forward, _normal) * _normal;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    _normal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
}

private void Flip()
{
    isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Ground") is_ground = true;
}
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Ground") is_ground = false;
}
}
```

Но после этого игрок стал медленно падать. Я изменил в RigidBody 2D параметр Gravity Scale на 28 и стало работать все нормально, до тех пор пока я не начал делать прыжок. Игрок не прыгал. Даже когда я задал параметр Gravity Scale обратно на 1 то игрок все равно не прыгал, только медленно падал(я не ставил проверку на прикосновение с землей). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ты видео смотрел то или просто код скопировал, не разбираясь как он работает? `_ = Project(direction.normalized);` что это такое? На кой тебе метод Project, если ты его не используешь по назначению? Зачем тебе нормаль поверхности, если ты ее нигде не используешь? Ты из разных гайдов покопировал код, не понимая как он работает, у тебя появляется баг, а исправить ты его не можешь, потому что не понимаешь почему он возникает и пытаешься костылить, изменяя гравити скейл.

Comment: А не прыгает и не падает у тебя, потому что ты телепортируешь игрока (метод Move), затем на него воздействует физика, его скорость увеличивается, а затем ты снова телепортируешь его и скорость обнуляется. Либо делай передвижение, соответственно прыжки и т.д., используя только физику, либо смотри следующее видео автора про то, как делать прыжок.